# How do I perform math on every other number in a list?

Tags: python, list

E.g.: How do I change

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
```

to this:

```
a = [2,2,6,4]
```

so every other element is doubled?

Comment: This really doesn't deserve a downvote - although some 'prior effort shown' goes a long way! - and I was quite surprised by a valid solution I've not seen before; it isn't "perform math on *every* number in a list", which would be worth a gentle clubbing of a plush seal doll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it in place, you can use slice assignment:

```
>>> a[::2] = [x*2 for x in a[::2]]
>>> a
[2, 2, 6, 4]
```

Comment: That (using the slice in *both* the input and output) is quite neat.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through every other index:

```
for index in range(0, len(your_list), 2):
    your_list[index] *= 2
```

You can also do it using slice assignment, as @mgilson notes:

```
your_list[::2] = [x*2 for x in your_list[::2]]
```

While this is certainly more concise, it may also be more confusing for the average person reading through the code - assigning to a slice with a non-default skip factor isn't very intuitive.

Comment: It's fairly intuitive for the `numpy` crowd I think -- But less so for those who aren't used to `numpy` and slicing all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to take two steps at a time a little more intuitive, like this

```
for i in range(len(yourList)/2):
    yourList[2*i] = 2*yourList[2*i]
```

Comment: Might want `len(yourList) // 2` for python3.x compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Though I do like the neat tricks used in the other answers, perhaps a more verbose and less-language specific explanation of what's going on is as follows:

```
for i in range(0, len(a)):   # Iterate through the list
    if i%2 == 0:             # If the remainder of i ÷ 2 is equal to 0...
        a[i] = a[i] * 2      # Change the current element to twice what it was
```